# OpenMP offload pinned memory

Tags: gpu, openmp, pinned-memory

I want to allocate page locked memory on host so that I get high bandwidth during data transfers. In CUDA, `cudaMallocHost` can be used to do this. How can I pin memory in OpenMP offloading?

Currently I am using normal `malloc`, but the data transfers are too slow. I am unable to find any option to pin memory in the OpenMP offloading documentation. There is the `pinned` trait for OpenMP, but I'm not sure how to work with that or if it even is the correct answer.

Comment: While OpenMP 5.0 supports [memory management via allocators](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse35.html#x211-10400003.7) (not the C++ kind) which have a `omp_atk_pinned` trait, this [isn't supported for NVIDIA HPC compilers](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/compilers/hpc-compilers-user-guide/index.html#openmp-subset). No idea if it works with GCC. The [official examples](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-5-0-1.pdf) provide an example of using the allocators (chapter "Memory Model", section "Memory Allocators"), but not for pinned memory specifically.